# How to turn off "Enable WiFi" alert message on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

When I disable Wi-Fi and open "Maps" I get the message:

> **Location Accuracy**
>
> Turning on Wi-Fi will improve
>
> location accuracy.

Can this message be disabled?

I know, I can just leave WiFi enabled, but I don't want to do this. When I am in airplane mode, I don't want to get notified that I am offline.

Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want to jailbreak my iPhone. I am currently running iOS 7.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works

Settings>Privacy>Location Services>System Services (all the way at the bottom) and toggling wifi networking.

Comment: The original poster asked to disable the *Message*, not WiFi generally.

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning off location services. This is a setting under Settings:Privacy:Location Services.